# Knockout JS code for updating row index number in the html element even when rows are added or deleted

Tags: knockout.js

For Example,

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="row"><span data-bind="text: rowIndex"></span></div>
    <div class="row"><span data-bind="text: rowIndex"></span></div>
    <div class="row"><span data-bind="text: rowIndex"></span></div>
    <div class="row"><span data-bind="text: rowIndex"></span></div>
</div>


<button>Delete Row</button>
<button>Add Row</button>
```

So, whenever I delete or add rows dynamically, that current row index value should be placed inside that span element.

Knockout binding code is required for this example.

Comment: Maybe give the docs a good read first? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html Everything you need is on that page.

Comment: As @Tomalak mentioned do refer doc's before lining up to check the posted answer which will be very helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/v651zqad/1/)

Now when you click on Add you will get corresponding index which starts from `0` which will be same in case of delete you get the deleted index value .

**View Model:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.index=ko.observable(0);
        self.loops = ko.observableArray([new list("Steve0"),new list("Steve1"),new list("Steve2")]);

        self.remove=function(index,val){
           self.index(index);
           self.loops.remove(val); 
         }

        self.Add=function(no){
            self.index(no);
           self.loops.push(new list("Steve"+no)); 
         }
};

 function list(name) {
       this.name=ko.observable(name);
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**View :**

```
<div><span>Index Picker <button data-bind="text:index"></button></span ></div> 
<div class="row">
    <span> Click to add row <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: function(){$root.Add(loops().length)}"/></span>
</div>
<div class="group" data-bind="foreach:loops">
    <div class="row">
        <span data-bind="text:$index()"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<input type="button"  value="remove" data-bind="click: function(){$root.remove($index(),$data)}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do mark it and upvote if you feel the answer is helpful . cheers